# Twitter widget: Custom Scroll Bar?

Tags: jquery, twitter, widget, scrollbar

I'm using twitter widget + Jquery Custom Content Scroller (http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) and I wonder if it's possible to change embedded widget's scrollbar to my own stylized?

The thing is that the website uses custom scrollbars and twitter's scrollbar looks ugly (default). I can't seem to find proper element to select and change via        `$(".element").mCustomScrollbar();`

Perhaps in another dimension it could be possible to select all the elements under wrapper class and apply to each this `mCustomScrollbar()` function... but i have no idea if it's possible or how to implement it.